# Stuck Floating Ad Banner at Bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I have  a quick question that has me stumped. On [this page](http://www.nbspeedway.com/live-timing.html) I have a floating banner at the bottom of the screen for a Google Ad. On my desktop, the following code is working correctly:

```
<div style="left:0;position: fixed;text-align:center;bottom: 0px;width:100%;z-index:9999;">

   <!-- GOOGLE AD CODE -->

</div>
```

The ad is supposed to float at the bottom of the page and stay there while you scroll. However, when I switch to my iPhone, the banner just stays stuck to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Position:Fixed; keeps the banner fixed on your screen indefinitely. Unless you specify differently for iPhone via media query, it will do the same thing, always stays on window, at same position as desktop viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to also give your body or whatever DIV that ad is inside of a relative position as well:

```
#main-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

<div style="left:0px; position:absolute; text-align:center; bottom: 0px;width:100%; z-index:9999;">.....</div>
```

In this case, it would look something like this with a Absolute position for the Ad div and relative for your content container. http://pasteboard.co/1gPmvBoK.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:30px;
width:100%;
background:#999;
}
#footer{
position:absolute;
top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

from http://www.flashjunior.ch/school/footers/fixed.cfm